# Is there a good method of Identifying a triangle that is utterly redundant on a polygon?

Tags: math, 3d, polygon, triangulation, 3d-modelling

I'm trying to write a function for C++ that can examine a union of two polygons and eliminate any leftover faces that didn't get correctly culled because of floating point error or various other small-number glitchy reasons.

Is there a good method by which one can identify a 3D triangle that is completely coplanar and contained within other faces on a 3D polygon and thus is completely redundant?

It's easy enough to detect a triangle within another TRIANGLE, but I'm looking for a situation where I can detect a redundant triangle that might cross and be contained several triangles that form a flat plane.

[image]

For example, in the picture above, assuming all vertices are in one plane, the red triangle is completely unnecessary and will only result in z-fighting.  And yet I can't seem to come up with a good technique that covers all bases for saying "the red one can be removed."

Any suggestions?

Comment: this is tough, but seems like it should be easier if you had planar n-gons in the model which were converted to triangles before rendering. As it is, you would probably have to do some algo on each triangle to check if it is coplanar with it's neighbors and make groups of coplanar triangles, and then check if any triangle is completely contained by any of these groups of triangles, which gets a lot harder if they aren't convex shapes

Comment: On your picture, the union of all the triangles is a convex polygon. When that is the case, the problem is much easier than in the general case. Is that guaranteed to be the case?

Comment: Hi @Stef, no, nothing's guaranteed.  My initial thought is to take all the coplanar triangles, flatten them to the plane, and test each one against all the rest to see if it's inside a polygon formed by all the others, and reject if so.  I guess my problem then becomes "how to get the perimeter of a bunch of triangulated triangles."  I'll open another question.

Comment: It seem what you want is to find all non-manifold triangles in your mesh. All triangles must share an edge with exactly 3 other triangles (except triangles at the boundary, if there is a boundary). Non-manifold triangles are those that only share a point with other triangle or share one edge with other triangle and are not at the boundary. This is a topological problem, you don't need the actual geometry, you need only the connectivity or graph to find the non-manifold triangles of your mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the solution I came up with here in case this question ever can help anyone with a similar problem.  What I did was:

1. Identify all triangles lying in the same plane
2. Rotate those into 2D triangles along that plane (this step is to reduce floating point precision problems and reduce the math needed in the next step)
3. If any given triangle has ALL THREE POINTS  within other triangles in this list it is redundant and can be removed.

Comment: False positive if the polygon is not convex: https://i.imgur.com/iNNfEQ7.png

Comment: @Stef I actually had that situation come up.  Solution is to identify points where a triangle is crossing the lines of a triangle it's "inside" and do a check of the midpoint there.